# how to change the look of components in ControlsFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, controlsfx

I implemented the ControlsFX TableFilter in my project and it work fine, but the problem is how can I make the component of the filter look likes the desgin in the back

I used JFoenix Library for my desgin https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix

[image]